# Unable to register new tile on Wear OS

Tags: android, wear-os, wear-os-tiles

I have just created a TileServiceProvider based on the sample given by google. In the google sample, registration is done using code in the androidManifest.xml file.

But if trying to add a Tile on the watch, it does not work. The sample app is not able to register the tile successfully either. Are we missing some information about registering tiles?

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.wear.tiles.messaging.MessagingTileService"
    android:label="@string/messaging_tile_label"
    android:description="@string/tile_description"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"
    android:permission="com.google.android.wearable.permission.BIND_TILE_PROVIDER">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="androidx.wear.tiles.action.BIND_TILE_PROVIDER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="androidx.wear.tiles.PREVIEW"
        android:resource="@drawable/tile_messaging" />
</service>
```

Comment: What error are you facing? Is the app launching on the watch but there's no Tile?

Comment: The app loads fine. The tile is never seen by watch or phone in the tiles list. I have also found out that Google are saying it will be resolved in the update for spring 2021...this has not happened yet.

Answer (score 3):

Google have mentioned fixing this problem in the spring 2021 update for the tiles library. It's still currently not fixed.

Comment: Can confirm that the example provided by Google doesn’t work for me either, so it seems to be a general problem instead of anything specifically that you’re doing wrong.

Comment: Had a chat with google. Seems we will need to wait till sometime in summer 2021. More info in this ticket: 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190788869

Answer (score 1):

Tiles are available for 3rd party developer, since August.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/08/sharing-tiles-with-your-smartwatch-users.html